# How to try queue again in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to send SMS using my laravel project for that purpose I wrote function in `MessageController` named `sendSms`. I am pushing message data to a queue named `SendScheduledSms` and handler as follows.

```
public function handle()
    {
        $sentsms = App::make('App\Http\Controllers\MessageController')->sendSms($this->post_data);
    }
```

Sending SMS works properly. `$sentsms` is the status of sent SMS. There are two values for `$status`, `success` and `fail`. I want to re-try sending same SMS if status is `fail`. How can I do that?
Now when `sendSms` executed, it deletes the queue.

I am using database queue.

Can anyone help?

Comment: when your sending sms failed,try to create an another queue what will send that sms again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to trigger Laravel Queue's native retry functionality, your Job `handle` method will need to throw an error at some point.

```
if ($sentsms == 'fail') {
    throw new Exception('SMS failed to send.');
}
```

If you have a `failed_jobs` table set up the job should be moved there by Laravel.
See the documentation on [Retrying failed jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#retrying-failed-jobs).

In your console schedule method set the `--tries` flag to have Laravel automatically rerun failed jobs.

```
$schedule->command("queue:work --tries=3")->everyMinute();
```